# How can I make my program continue after asking for user input?

Tags: java

I have to create an `ArrayList` of students in the College class, each object in the arraylist include name, studentid, address and quizscore

I am working on the tester class and I need my program to continue running to create a large arrayList so I can perform commands such as, find to look up studentnumbers or find the highest scores.

I have created such methods and in my tester class I implemented Scanner to obtain commands from keyboard, but after it does a command, i.e add student it terminates the program so when I want to look back at what I've just added (with "find" for instance) the program has terminated and that newly created object is gone.

What can I do to my tester class to keep it "running" and allow the array list to grow.

Comment: post your code and problem

Comment: Please post code snippets of the problem. From your question, I understand that the command input code should be in a loop and a sentinel should be used to come out of the loop.

Comment: It's impossible for us to help without seeing your code.  Otherwise all we can do is guess at the problem...

Comment: Sound like a good for a `do-while` loop...

Answer (score 1):

To keep data between executions of the program, you will need to persist it. The usual way is to write it to a file in some format. If the objects in the `ArrayList` are serializable, you can simply write the entire array to an `ObjectOutputStream` that writes a `FileOutputStream` to save, and then restore it on the next program start by wrapping an `ObjectInputStream` around a `FileInputStream`.

Search the web for *Java data persistence* to find many approaches to persisting data, including alternatives to my suggestion and lots of tutorial code.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. If you want to keep the array have the program running. Preferably a multi threaded program with a thread in never ending loop. But still if you want to persist add a database.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly and my guess was correct:

To keep your program running You can use while loop until your command will be equal to "quit" or something else, such as

```
while(command.compareTo("quit")!=0) {
      //your code here
}
```

This way your program will be running until you enter quit to terminate it.

You can write the data from your array to the txt file and load it each time your program starts. This way you will keep data.

Answer (score -2):

Use a private instance variable for your ArrayList so your program will keep track of it once your method has terminated.

You can declare it like this:

```
private ArrayList nameOfYourList;
```

Comment: The question is to retain the objects once the program is terminated.